# Creating a DIR list and adding text to the beginning and end

Tags: batch-file, echo, dir

What I am trying to do is list files including the file path, then add text and parentheses to them. So, i start with:

1.jpg

2.jpg

3.jpg

And I use

```
DIR /s/b /on *.JPG > LIST_JPG.DAT
```

To get them to be

c:/foldera/folderb/1.jpg

c:/foldera/folderb/2.jpg

c:/foldera/folderb/2.jpg

The next part I need to do is add text to the beginning that reads "exifread -TEXT" in front of it, and put parentheses around the

```
@ECHO OFF 

FOR %%i IN (*.JPG) DO ECHO exifread -TEXT "%%i"
```

Which gets me

exifread -TEXT " 1.jpg "

Which is so close, but what I need it to be is

exifread -TEXT "c:/foldera/folderb/1.jpg"

Any ideas? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost done

```
for %%a in (*.jpg) do echo exifread -TEXT "%%~fa"
```

Where `%%~fa` is the file referenced in replaceable parameter `%%a` but with full path. See `for /?` for the list of available modifiers

For a recursive version,

```
for /r "c:\foldera" %%a in (*.jpg) do echo exifread -TEXT "%%~fa"
```

That will do the same operation but for all `.jpg` files under the indicated starting folder and below.

Comment: That's amazing! It does exactly what I need it to!